# How to stop JQ filter from matching key to every permutation of the other keys

Tags: json, iteration, jq

I'm trying to parse a collection of JSON objects like this:

```
{
"stage": [
{
"name": "Stage 1",
"weeks": [
{
 "name": "Week 1",
 "matches": [
  {
   "teams": [
    {
     "name": "San Francisco Shock",
     "score": "0",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10223"
    },
    {
     "name": "Los Angeles Valiant",
     "score": "4",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10223"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "teams": [
    {
     "name": "Shanghai Dragons",
     "score": "0",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10224"
    },
    {
     "name": "Los Angeles Gladiators",
     "score": "4",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10224"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "teams": [
    {
     "name": "Dallas Fuel",
     "score": "1",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10225"
    },
    {
     "name": "Seoul Dynasty",
     "score": "2",
     "score_url": "https://overwatchleague.com/matches/10225"
    }
   ]
  },
```

Etc, etc.

I'm trying to get this into a format that another language that isn't super friendly to JSON can handle more easily by condensing it into something like this:

```
{"matches":
    [
     {
      "team1": "San Francisco Shock",
      "t1score": "0",
      "team2": "Los Angeles Valiant",
      "t2score": "4"
     },
     { ... }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to use this jq filter to accomplish this:

```
jq '.stage[] | {matches: [{team1: .weeks[].matches[].teams[0].name, t1score: 
.weeks[].matches[].teams[0].score, team2: .weeks[].matches[].teams[1].name, 
t2score: .weeks[].matches[].teams[1].score}]}'
```

The issue with this is that it matches every instance of, say, the "name" key with the value "San Francisco Shock" against all permutations of scores and names in the array "matches". I'm pretty new to jq, but I think that this is happening because I'm simply telling it to map all of the elements in "weeks" and "matches" together through the filter. Is this correct? And what would a filter that actually did what I'm looking to try and do look like? I haven't found an easy way to keep the filter from matching beyond the scope of the "teams" array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to "pull" the `.weeks[]` iterator forward, and to `map` over the `.matches` array:

```
.stage[]
|.weeks[]
| {matches:
    (.matches
     | map({team1:   .teams[0].name,
            t1score: .teams[0].score,
            team2:   .teams[1].name, 
            t2score: .teams[1].score }) ) }
```

## Output

```
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "team1": "San Francisco Shock",
      "t1score": "0",
      "team2": "Los Angeles Valiant",
      "t2score": "4"
    },
    {
      "team1": "Shanghai Dragons",
      "t1score": "0",
      "team2": "Los Angeles Gladiators",
      "t2score": "4"
    },
    {
      "team1": "Dallas Fuel",
      "t1score": "1",
      "team2": "Seoul Dynasty",
      "t2score": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I see, so I need to break it up into multiple filters piping their results into the next. Thank you!